# Shooting at a target problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There is the problem:
I'm shooting at a target 10 (for example) times and my chance to get a point is M (in percents).
How can i find probability that I will have a prime number in final score.

For example if M = 100 => Probability = 0.

Sorry for my English!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split it into **disjoint events**, and then sum up their probabilities.

For consistency, let $P=\frac{M}{100}$ denote the probability of getting $1$ point.

Then the probability of getting a prime number of points is the sum of the following:

- The probability of getting exactly $2$ points: $\binom{10}{2}\cdot(P)^2\cdot(1-P)^{10-2}$
- The probability of getting exactly $3$ points: $\binom{10}{3}\cdot(P)^3\cdot(1-P)^{10-3}$
- The probability of getting exactly $5$ points: $\binom{10}{5}\cdot(P)^5\cdot(1-P)^{10-5}$
- The probability of getting exactly $7$ points: $\binom{10}{7}\cdot(P)^7\cdot(1-P)^{10-7}$

Comment: Ok thanks I get it!

Comment: @JamesRodrigues: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it :)